# Excel - automatically filling in a column with V1, V2, V3, etc…

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need some help filling a column on excel, all I need it to say is “V(whatever number I’m on)”, and going down the column with each cell looking like V1, V2, V3, etc

I don’t know excel that well but I imagine the formula could look like this, if V is a constant,

V(SUM(above cell + 1))

But, I have no idea how to format that with the numbers and letters

Thanks so much

Comment: Something like `="V"&SEQUENCE(100)` if you have Office 365. Or `="V"&ROW(A1)` and drag down.

Comment: `="V" & ROW()`? you may need to adjust, for example, if your list starts on the third row, you would use `="V" & ROW()-2`

Answer (score 1):

`="V"&RIGHT(INDEX($1:$1048576,ROW()-1,COLUMN()),LEN(INDEX($1:$1048576,ROW()-1,COLUMN()))-1)+1` does what you described, but if you name the cell above (for instance `A1`) you could shorten it to `="V"&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)+1`.

If you have Office 365 `="V"&SEQUENCE(10)` spills V1 up to V10.
`="V"&SEQUENCE(10,,5)` will start at V5 and spill up to V15. No need for a cell above then.

In older versions you can also use `="V"&ROW()` to get a counter when dragged down. If you want to adjust it to a different start point you can add or subtract a number after the `ROW()`.